# Config NGINX to GZip Font Files? ( Different gzip_types for different directories)

Tags: nginx, optimization, gzip

### SOLUTION: It turns out it is not my config / NGINX faults - my DNS provider, cloudflare, is preventing the fonts from being GZipped for some reason

I'm using NGINX with GZIP_Static module installed.

I'm trying to get my .SVG/.TTF @FONT-FACE font files to be served via GZip, as there will be a reduction in about 50% file size. I've added the following mimetypes to the mime.types file:

```
image/svg+xml                         svg;
application/x-font-ttf                ttf;
font/opentype                         otf;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
font/x-woff                           woff;
```

The fonts are all placed in a single folder, so I first tried setting up folder-specific gzip settings as follows:

```
location /sites/default/files/fontyourface/local_fonts/ {
      gzip_types image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype ; 
}
```

That didn't work, so I tried just adding the Mime types to the "universal" gzip_types definition in nginx.conf - that didn't work either.

I've gone in and manually gzipped the font files so GZIP_Static can be used. That didn't work either.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong / how I can set NGINX up to return the GZIP'd versions of only .SVG and .TTF files?

Comment: Font files never change; why not preprocess them?

Comment: They are pre-compressed; the problem here was the headers were not stating the contents as GZipped

Comment: What does your DNS provider have to do with your web server (other than telling others how to get to it of course)?

Answer (score 3):

CloudFlare will only gzip TTFs if they are transferred with one of these mime types:

- font/ttf
- application/ttf
- application/x-ttf

Source: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-CloudFlare-gzip-